# Combine path from a list of objects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ienumerable

I have an `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` object, and I want to create a path from all the `Name` attributes.
I did:

```
foreach (var item in Items)
{
    path += item.Name+"\\";
}
```

While `Items` is `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class SomeClass
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string Type { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; internal set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; internal set; }
}
```

How can I do it in a better way than foreach?

`Path.Combine()` can work with arrays, but I need to isolate the `Name` attribute.

Comment: What is the issue with foreach? Please elaborate.

Comment: I just thought there is a better way with Linq

Comment: LINQ is definitely more readable and easier to write. Just be aware of the performance implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
Path.Combine(items.Select(o => o.Name))
```

Comment: "The best overloaded method match for 'System.IO.Path.Combine(params string[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Probably the argument requires a `ToArray` in the end: `Path.Combine(items.Select(o => o.Name).ToArray())`